# Styling third party elements with React inline styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to use react to style elements generated by a third party library. In the below snippet I achieve what I want with css. I'd like to do this with javascript so that I can have users define custom colour schemes.

```css
.ThirdPartyDiv {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyDiv">
  <div class="ThirdPartyDiv">
    Some Content
  </div>
</div>
```

By "user defined" I mean a user will specify values for `colour1, colour2, colour3, etc` which is saved in a database. When the site is loaded (on a given page) we will load this info and build a stylesheet from it.

Comment: You can't inline style it right ? You want to do a conditional rendering using plain js ?

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question? what do you by "users define" ? where are you storing this info? how is the user meant to set a theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can have conditional css by using plain javascript. Create a style element and append a cssRule. Like this :

```
const userColor = "green" //Get from db of course

var style = document.createElement("style");
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
document.head.appendChild(style);

style.sheet.insertRule(".ThirdPartyDiv { color:"+userColor+"; }", 0);
```

It will insert a styleDomElement to your page. Load the file when you start your app.

EDIT: doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule